# AWS Lambda - Copy monthly snapshots to another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ebs

I am trying to run a lambda that will kick off on a schedule to copy all snapshots taken the day prior to another region for DR purposes. I have a bit of code but it seems to not work as intended.

Symptoms:

1. It's grabbing the same snapshots multiple times and copying them
2. It always errors out on 2 particular snapshots, I don't know enough coding to write a log to figure out why. These snapshots work if I manually copy them though.

```py
import boto3
from datetime import date, timedelta

SOURCE_REGION = 'us-east-1'
DEST_REGION = 'us-west-2'

ec2_source      = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = SOURCE_REGION)
ec2_destination = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = DEST_REGION)

snaps           = ec2_source.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['self'])['Snapshots']
yesterday       = date.today() - timedelta(days = 1)
yesterday_snaps = [ s for s in snaps if s['StartTime'].date() == yesterday ]

for yester_snap in yesterday_snaps:
    DestinationSnapshot = ec2_destination.copy_snapshot(
        SourceSnapshotId = yester_snap['SnapshotId'],
        SourceRegion = SOURCE_REGION,
        Encrypted = True,
        KmsKeyId='REMOVED FOR SECURITY',
        DryRun = False
    )
    DestinationSnapshotID = DestinationSnapshot['SnapshotId']
    ec2_destination.create_tags(Resources=[DestinationSnapshotID],
        Tags=yester_snap['Tags']
    )
    waiter = ec2_destination.get_waiter('snapshot_completed')
    waiter.wait(
        SnapshotIds=[DestinationSnapshotID],
        DryRun=False,
        WaiterConfig={'Delay': 10,'MaxAttempts': 123}
    )
```

Comment: Why are you waiting for the snapshots to complete? You do not need to. What is the error message you are receiving, and on which line is the error being generated?

Comment: There appears to be a limit of 20 snapshots copy processes for the region, it used to be 5 but must have recently been updated. Do you know a way around that? I get this error when I take the waiter out.
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ResourceLimitExceeded) when calling the CopySnapshot operation: Too many snapshot copies in progress. The limit is 20 for this destination region.","

Comment: Ah! According to [AWS Service Quotas - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html), there is a limit of **5** Concurrent snapshot copies to a single destination Region. I guess that means you need to do a bit of waiting.

Answer (score 0):

**Debugging**

You can debug by simply putting `print()` statements in your code.

For example:

```py
for yester_snap in yesterday_snaps:
    print('Copying:', yester_snap['SnapshotId'])
    DestinationSnapshot = ec2_destination.copy_snapshot(...)
```

The logs will appear in CloudWatch Logs. You can access the logs via the Monitoring tab in the Lambda function. Make sure the Lambda function has `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` permissions so that it can write to CloudWatch Logs.

**Today/Yesterday**

Be careful about your definition of `yesterday`. Amazon EC2 instances run in the `UTC` timezone, so your concept of a `today` and `yesterday` might not match what is happening.

It might be better to add a tag to snapshots after they are copied (eg 'copied') rather than relying on dates to figure out which ones to copy.

**CloudWatch Events rule**

Rather than running this program once per day, an alternative method would be:

- Create an **Amazon CloudWatch Events** rule that triggers on Snapshot creation:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EBS Snapshot Notification"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "event": [
      "createSnapshot"
    ]
  }
}
```

- Configure the rule to trigger an **AWS Lambda function**
- In the Lambda function, **copy the Snapshot** that was just created

This way, the Snapshots are created immediately and there is no need to search for them or figure out which Snapshots to copy

Comment: Thank you, using the print statement I was able to troubleshoot that I needed to add KMS decrypt permissions on my IAM role. This allowed those few snapshots that were erroring out to complete successfully. I have a weird issue now where it will take the same couple snapshots and copy them multiple times, if I take the waiter off it seems to grab everything it can but the 20 limit is stopping me from completing the task successfully.

Comment: Does the `print()` line show that you are copying the same Snapshot multiple times? Or is it because it is copying the same snapshot on different days because of the "Today/Yesterday" stuff I mention above? By the way, you can specify tags via `TagSpecifications ` when creating the snapshot.

Comment: The log told me it was the same snapshot ID. Since Lambda has a limit of 15 minutes, I don't think that is enough time for me to copy all of my machines (~15) over. I think I need to either look at using the CLI or breaking it up into a multiple Lambdas.

Comment: I recommend the approach I mention above, where the mere creation of a Snapshot automatically triggers an AWS Lambda function that copies it to another Region. This way, there is no need to loop or wait. It just happens automatically.

Comment: [Copy Snapshot API now supports adding tags while copying snapshots](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/copy-snapshot-api-supports-adding-tags-while-copying-snapshots/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that is great. Just to clarify I could use the above Cloudwatch method and have it kick off at the start of say the 27th of every month and it will automatically copy all snapshots created that day?

Comment: No. My recommended method is to automatically trigger the AWS Lambda method **immediately after every Snapshot is created**. It will then immediately copy the snapshot to the other region. This is assuming that you want _every_ snapshot copied. If you only want certain snapshots copied, you could tag the snapshots when they are created and then have the Lambda function only copy specifically-tagged snapshots. It depends on your requirements.